# выполнить код, если оператор if равен заданному числу

Tags: php, массивы, if

У меня есть 2 массив $arr1 $arr2 если рандом дает цифру 1 в цикле выполняется $arr1 если 2 то выполняется $arr2

```
$arr1 = [
[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Name',
    'link1' => 'fb.com',
    'link2' => 'vk.com',
    'link3' => 'ok.ru'
    ],
[
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Name',
    'link1' => 'fb.com',
    'link2' => 'vk.com',
    'link3' => 'ok.ru'
    ]

];

$arr2 = [
[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Name',
    'link1' => 'fb.com',
    'link2' => 'vk.com',
    'link3' => 'ok.ru'
    ],
[
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Name',
    'link1' => 'fb.com',
    'link2' => 'vk.com',
    'link3' => 'ok.ru'
    ]

];

shuffle($arr);

shuffle($arr2);

$rand = rand(1,2);

if($rand == 1) {
    
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    
    echo $arr[$i]['name'].PHP_EOL;
    echo $arr[$i]['id'].PHP_EOL;
    echo $arr[$i]['link1'].PHP_EOL;
    echo $arr[$i]['link2'].PHP_EOL;
    #если итерпция 2 выполняется нужно добавлять еще один ключ 'link3' в итерации 2 будет 3 ссылки.
    if($i = 2) {
    echo $arr[$i]['link3'].PHP_EOL;
    }
}
}

if($rand == 2) {
    
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    
    echo $arr2[$i]['name'].PHP_EOL;
    echo $arr2[$i]['id'].PHP_EOL;
    echo $arr2[$i]['link1'].PHP_EOL;
    echo $arr2[$i]['link2'].PHP_EOL;
    #если итерпция 2 выполняется нужно добавлять еще один ключ 'link3' в итерации 2 будет 3 ссылки.
    if($i = 2) {
    echo $arr2[$i]['link3'].PHP_EOL;
    }
}
}
```

в итерация 1 будет 2 ссылки 'link1' 'link2' в итерация 2 будет 3 ссылки 'link1' 'link2' 'link3'

Я нуб, просто эксприментирую. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: сложите свои в два массива в еще один, `$arr = [$arr1, $arr2]` и выберите из него случайный, с ним и работайте потом. Или сделайте `$res = rand() == 1 ? $arr1 : $arr2` для частного случая с 2мя массивами.  `foreach` еще оператор имеется. а `if ($i = 2)` всегда истинно

Comment: А если массивов больше чем 2? У меня их много это просто пример кода.

Comment: тогда сложите всех их в массив и выберите случайный индекс через `array_rand`, возьмите соответствующий элемент-массив, и ему уже shuffle и дальнейшую работу

Comment: Хорошо объяснил бро но я нуб. Хэ не знаю как работать с array_rand и как указать итерацию в foreach. Если не трудно можете написатб код с array_rand

Comment: если я напишу код, то ты так нубом и останешься. Те кто здесь отвечает, готовы потратить толику времени, чтобы помочь нубу стать  не нубом, для этого последний должен с подсказками и документацией самостоятельно пытаться решать задачу. Тратить свое время просто так тут никому не интересно.

Comment: Ок $arr = [$arr1, $arr2, $arr3]; $key = array_rand($arr, 1); foreach($key as $array) примерно так да? Все остально выполняется с if?

Comment: Все равно спасибо за подсказку.